# What does CTRL+V do in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

In vim while in `insert` mode, if I press CTRL+V I'm thrown into what is known as `x mode (^[,^D...)` and when I press a key (the escape key for instance) I end up with `^[` or something else that starts with `^`.  It also turns green in my editor.

What is this, and what is it used for?

Comment: Are you sure that's Vim?  `Ctrl+V` (without the shift) has that meaning in several terminal emulators.  Perhaps tell us what terminal you are using.

Comment: @grochmal It's vim in Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [`:h i_CTRL-V`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V) (the `i_` indicates insert mode):

```
                                                i_CTRL-V
CTRL-V          Insert next non-digit literally.  For special keys, the
                terminal code is inserted.  It's also possible to enter the
                decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character
                i_CTRL-V_digit.
                The characters typed right after CTRL-V are not considered for
                mapping.  {Vi: no decimal byte entry}
                Note: When CTRL-V is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can
                often use CTRL-Q instead i_CTRL-Q.
```

So, when you do `^v Esc`, you're literally entering the <kbd>Esc</kbd> character into the text - Vim will not do whatever it usually does. The <kbd>Esc</kbd> character is usually represented as `^[`, the `^` being <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> will usually get you the equivalent of pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The [Ubuntu ASCII manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/ascii.7.html) is useful in visualising the mapping:

```
010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H
011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I
012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J
013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K
014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L
015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
...
033   27    1B    ESC (escape)                133   91    5B    [
```

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> in this case has no effect, Vim sees the same thing as when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.